# find obj type of jQuery result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code produce ["AM123","DR2","F","99"] from the console.log.
Now I want to see what is the type of the result.

The code producing the result is :

```
$(".stock_splitdata").each(function() {
var $table = $(this);

var values = $("td", $table).map(function() {
return $(this).text();
}).get();
$table.replaceWith(values.join(" "));

});
```

My purpose to view the object type is that I want to split the result into four and join them with different padding like ["AM123","DR2","F","99"]  become AM123-----DR2-F--99------

Update: 19/10/2012:

I found the solution as below.But if anyone can optimise the code, please fell free to do so.

```
if(subtableName == 'stock_splitdata'){

               $(".stock_splitdata").each(function() {
                    var $table = $(this);

                    var values = $("td", $table).map(function() {
                        return $(this).text();
                    }).get();

                    var tmpSKU = padRight(10, values[0], '&nbsp;');
                    tmpSKU = tmpSKU + padRight(4, values[1], '&nbsp;');
                    tmpSKU = tmpSKU + padRight(4, values[2], '&nbsp;');
                    tmpSKU = tmpSKU + padRight(4, values[3], '&nbsp;');

                    $table.replaceWith(tmpSKU);

                });

           }
```

Comment: What do you mean by type of object? You have an array of strings.

Comment: I want to double confirm it is an array. I use split, but couldn't.The error says split is not a function

Comment: so if it is an array, how do I split them and pad them to the format I want?

Comment: What is logic behind your _padding_?

Comment: split them into 4 group with the following padding for each group: 10 char    4 char   3 char   8 char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user `$.type()` [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/)

you should try `$.type(values)` also `values instanceof Array`;

```
jQuery.type(true) === "boolean"
jQuery.type(3) === "number"
jQuery.type("test") === "string"
jQuery.type(function(){}) === "function"
jQuery.type([]) === "array"
jQuery.type(new Date()) === "date"
jQuery.type(/test/) === "regexp"
Everything else returns "object" as its type.
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/cKNWr/1/)

for [more information](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/)

Comment: any idea how can I split array into 4 and pad them according to different group? I want to split them( ["AM123","DR2","F","99"] ) into 4 groups and pad to the following format: 10 char 4 char 3 char 8 char

Comment: you should try javascript `.split()` function

Comment: ok, after putting effort to get the array values, I can actually directly read the array using values[0] , values[1] ,values [2], values[3]...now i want to pad those values with empty space using these format values[0] => 10 char, values[1] => 4 char, values[2] => 3 char, values[3] => 8 char. Any idea how to do right pad  with empty string using jQuery?